# Issues during Batch Transaction update in Firestore

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angular7

**Functionality:**

I have a function batchItemUpdate that gets a list of items. Each item has an array called batches.I am updating batches of each item in items list.As there can be a lot of items I am using batch writes to so so. Check the code below:

```
batchItemUpdate(items: Item[]) {

    var transactionBatch = this.afs.firestore.batch();

    items.forEach((item)=>{
        const sfDocRef = this.afs.firestore.collection('items').doc(item.id);
        transactionBatch.update(sfDocRef,
            {
                batches:item.batches
            });
    });
    return transactionBatch.commit();
}
```

**Issue:**
The transaction is committed successfully but only the latest batch in batches array is written. All other batch in the batches array in item is getting deleted.

```
if previously item.batches was [1,2,3,4]
to be updated with [1,2,3,5]
now item.batches is [5]
```

Answer (score 0):

When you update a field in a document with a value, it will completely overwrite the previous contents of that field.  The fact that it's an "update" doesn't merge new values into the field, no matter its type (looks like you are making it an array).

If you want to unconditionally add values to an array, you could:

1. Read the document, change the field's value in memory, then write it back out do the document.
2. Or, use [FieldValue.arrayUnion()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array) to add values. This works for only one value at a time, so you would have to use it repeatedly.

You might have to abandon the idea of using a batch, unless you really need all the write to become effective at the same time.  That's the primary use case of a batch.